# Objects not being removed from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which is called `order_book`, inside `order_book` there is `asks` and `asks` all have a `price` assigned to them.

I'm trying to remove any asks from the `order_book` array where the price is below my `minsell` value but it is just doing nothing.

Does anyone know why this is happening or a way to resolve it?

I'm sorry this is very basic, my first day in proper JavaScript.

```
if (order_book.asks[0].price < minsell) {
  order_book.asks.filter(Number, order_book.asks.price < minsell);
}
```

Comment: `filter` does not update array itself. You need to re-assign it after `filter`. Also, there is no need of the `if` there.

Comment: how would i reassign it to the same array? every time i do that i get an error. thank you

Comment: Please click edit, then scroll down and click the `[<>]` snippet editor. Add a relevant object and enough code for a [mcve] and describe expected output

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code:

```js
const order_book = {
  asks: [
    {
      price: 45
    },
    {
      price: 8
    }
  ]
}

order_book.asks = order_book.asks.filter(ask => {
  return ask.price < 10;
})

console.log(order_book.asks);
```

Output:

```
{
  "asks": [
    {
      "price": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is the opposite of what OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

You mean retrieve?

```js
const minsell = 20
const order_book = {
  asks: [
    {"price":"10","name":"Oliver Twist"},
    {"price":"20","name":"Tales of two cities"},
    {"price":"30","name":"Citizen Kane"}
  ]
};   

let filteredBooks = order_book.asks.filter(ask => ask.price >= minsell) 
console.log(filteredBooks)
```

Or actually remove (modifying the original object)

```js
const minsell = 20
const order_book = {
  asks: [
    {"price":"10","name":"Oliver Twist"},
    {"price":"20","name":"Tales of two cities"},
    {"price":"30","name":"Citizen Kane"}
  ]
};   

order_book.asks = order_book.asks.filter(ask => ask.price >= minsell) 
console.log(order_book)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter does not manipulate the original array directly, but creates a new one with the values which pass in the iterator (first param).
You can read more about filter on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
order_book.asks = order_book.asks.filter(ask => ask.price >= minsell)
```